# How to get stop all 3 radio buttons from being selected

Tags: javascript

I have got a 4 sets of Radio Button on my table Row.
Out of which I need 1 must be selected  and out of the remaining 3 only 2 need to be selected.

the 1st radio Button is a Must of Status in LN (Pass or Fail)
if Fail, then all the other buttons should get greyed out or shouldn't be selectable.
If yes, then out of the 3 sets only 2 should be allowed.
either OTP + ART Questions
Either InApp  + ART Questions.
Please help!!!!!!

```html
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Phone Number :: </b> <input type="text" name="phone" id="Call" maxlength="15" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <b>Status in LN :: </b> <input type="radio" name="gen" id="rd1" Value="Pass"> Pass
    <input type="radio" name="gen" id="rd2" value="Fail"> Fail &NonBreakingSpace;&NonBreakingSpace;
    <b> InApp Verification ::</b><input type="radio" name="gene" id="rd3" value="Pass"> Pass
    <input type="radio" name="gene" id="rd4" value="Fail"> Fail &NonBreakingSpace;&NonBreakingSpace;
    <b> ART Questions ::</b><input type="radio" name="geen" id="rd5" value="Pass"> Pass
    <input type="radio" name="geen" id="rd6" value="Fail"> Fail &NonBreakingSpace;&NonBreakingSpace; <br><br>
    <b>OTP :: </b> Phone :: <input type="text" name="cell" id="txt-cell" placeholder="Cell Phone"> OTP Code :: <input type="text" name="otp" id="otpc" placeholder="OTP Code">
    <input type="radio" name="genr" id="rd7" value="Pass"> Pass
    <input type="radio" name="genr" id="rd8" value="Fail"> Fail
    <input type="button" id="btnobc" value="Copy Outbound Data" onclick="obcall()" ;>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
  function obcall() {

    var rd1 = document.getElementById("rd1");
    var rd2 = document.getElementById("rd2");
    var rd3 = document.getElementById("rd3");
    var rd4 = document.getElementById("rd4");
    var rd5 = document.getElementById("rd5");
    var rd6 = document.getElementById("rd6");
    var rd7 = document.getElementById("rd7");
    var rd8 = document.getElementById("rd8");

    document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "\r\nPhone Number : [" + document.getElementById("Call").value + "], Status in LN :: ";

    if (rd1.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Pass"
    else if (rd2.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Fail"
    else document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + " Please select Status "

    document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "\r\nIn App :: "
    if (rd3.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Pass"
    else if (rd4.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Fail"
    else document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Please select Status"
    document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "\r\nMobile Number : [" + document.getElementById("txt-cell").value + "], OTP Code : [" + document.getElementById("otpc").value + "] ";
    if (rd7.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Pass"
    else if (rd8.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Fail"
    else document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Please select Status"
    document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "\r\nArt Questions :: ";
    if (rd5.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Pass"
    else if (rd6.checked == true)
      document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Fail"
    else document.casenotes.emminfo.value = document.casenotes.emminfo.value + "Please select Status"
  };
</script>
```